# Import class fails with ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying with this syntax to import and init a class in ES6. But the console says 'undefined property hej'.

Work.js

```
class Work {

    constructor() {

    }

    hej() {
        alert('hej');
    }
}

export default Work;
```

Main.js

```
import Work from './modules/work.js';


Work.hej();
```

Whats causing this error? How to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Your `Work` function has no `hej` property. `hej` is a property of the prototype that `new Work` would assign to an instance, so:

```
const w = new Work();
w.hej();
```

Or if you *want* to use it as `Work.hej();`, make it `static`:

```
class Work {
    static hej() {
//  ^^^^^^-----------------
        alert("hej");
    }
}
```

Then `Work.hej()` works, because `hej` is a static method (a method of `Work`, not of *instances* of `Work`).

---

If you use [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VIm50fvbi8dHtw5YMxhK?p=preview) on the most recent version of Chrome, it'll show that it's working (with an instance method). Here's the source:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <script type="module" src="work.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

`work.js`:

```
class Work {
    constructor() {
    }

    hej() {
        document.body.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode("hej")
        );
    }
}
export default Work;
```

`main.js`:

```
import Work from './work.js';

const w = new Work();
w.hej();
```

---

If you use [this one](http://plnkr.co/edit/MyhiKfloVSiTCYvPr9wg?p=preview) on the most recent version of Chrome, it'll show that it's working (with a static method). Here's the source:

`index.html` (same as above)

`work.js`:

```
class Work {
    constructor() {
    }

    static hej() {
        document.body.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode("hej")
        );
    }
}
export default Work;
```

`main.js`:

```
import Work from './work.js';

Work.hej();
```

---

**Note that module support in Chrome is really new**, you do need to be completely up-to-date (as I write this, late October 2017).

Comment: I see, thanks. What if i want hej to be a method? As my intention is.

Comment: @user2952238: I just realized I should have considered that option and was editing; hit refresh. :-)

Comment: hm, then i get this: _work2.default is not a constructor

Comment: @user2952238: Then something isn't as you've shown it. With what you've shown, and *only* the changes above (one or the other), both things work.